# Allow for tabbing within textarea input boxes

Tags: feature-request, editor

[Bootply](http://bootply.com/new) allows for tabbing within textarea input boxes, which makes it much easier to format code properly.  On SO hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> moves my cursor to the next input.

Is there any reason why this is not available on SO? I think it would be a useful feature.

Comment: That's why a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/) exists for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks for the link! However I noticed that I can't install this on Chrome since it's not in the webstore. http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts#comment11343_3247

Comment: You can install it [manually](http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

Comment: The hurdle is, how do we allow keyboard users to move between fields if we overload Tab to insert tabs. How do other sites handle this? The proposal might be legitimate if you suggested how we can deal with this while preserving accessibility.